# MySQL - Multiple values associated with a requested value

Tags: mysql, list

I have a table called releases, part of a 'music' database. The table consists of two columns; `cd_id`, `band_id`

I want to list the cd_id and the number of bands involved for each cd where two or more `band_id` are associated with one `cd_id` value.

Could you help me phrase this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an aggregate `COUNT()` with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
  cd_id,
  count(*) AS numbands
FROM releases
GROUP BY cd_id
HAVING numbands >= 2
```

The `COUNT(*)` coupled with the `GROUP BY cd_id` returns the number of `band_id` per `cd_id`, and in order to limit these to releases with 2+ `band_id`, a `HAVING` clause specifies `numbands` (the alias given to the count value) `>= 2`.

Note, this assumes each `band_id` is only listed once per `cd_id`. If that isn't the case, to get unique bands per cd, use

```
COUNT(DISTINCT band_id) AS numbands
```

instead of `COUNT(*) AS numbands`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that releases doesn't list the same band twice for a CD_ID

```
select CD_ID, count(*) 
from releases 
GROUP BY CD_ID
HAVING count(*) > 1
```